# Will explicitely named conditions generally be inlined?

Tags: compilation

This might be too broad, since I'm not talking about a specific language, but since it is such a basic concept it might be universal.

Is this:

```
too_long = array.length > MAX_LENGTH

if too_long; then
    ...
```

The same in modern compilers as:

```
if array.length > MAX_LENGTH; then
    ...
```

if the variable `too_long` is not used elsewhere?

I like the first version for clarity, but am wondering, if that is a recognized pattern.

Comment: You would need to mention a specific language for anything concrete. But yes, you can trust that an intelligent compiler will inline anything it thinks will be beneficial. Don't worry about stuff like this. Just write what is readable.

Comment: This is a common optimization, yes.  For any specific compiler/language you'd have to look at what that compiler does.